# Form Submit Action

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android. I have one application in which I'm planning to add App Rate function. I found below library for it

[Apprate Library](https://github.com/codemybrainsout/smart-app-rate)

```
final RatingDialog ratingDialog = new RatingDialog.Builder(this)
                .threshold(3)
                .session(7)
                .onRatingBarFormSumbit(new RatingDialog.RatingDialogFormListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFormSubmitted(String feedback) {

                    }
                }).build();

ratingDialog.show();
```

I have impemented it but there is nothing written for feedback email related code. Can some one please tell me where I should write my email so when user can submit feedback? Can I get an email?

Thanks!

Comment: Very vague. What email ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any action after submit would be done inside:

```
public void onFormSubmitted(String feedback) {
    // put the code here
}
```